# If statement with classic asp databinding

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using a WebForms gridview and I'm implementing edit/update function through js.  The problem is that I do not want an edit button for every row.  Is there a way to configure the asp:template field so that my edit button only shows up if that data row meets a certain condition?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ETA">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span id="jsEDateDataValue<%# Eval("ID") %>" 
            class="displayInline">
            <%# Eval("ETA") %>
        </span>
```

Below the above code, I have html inputs hidden by css and set to show up through the edit button.

In other words, how would I implement this psuedocode line?

```
<%# if (Eval("Status") == "closed" || Eval("Status") == "open") Response.Write("<input type='text' />"); %>
```

Comment: Can you bind in codebehind instead?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be quite the answer you wanted, but it might get you close, and should be considered more of pseudo-code than real working code.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="jsEDateDataValue" runat="server" CssClass="displayInline">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtYourBox" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>

Protected Sub YourGrid_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles YourGrid.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim jsEDateDataValue = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("jsEDateDataValue"), Panel)
        Dim txtYourBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtYourBox"), TextBox )
        jsEDateDataValue.Attributes.Add("data-id", e.Row.RowIndex) 'recreating something for javascript to use instead of jsEDateDataValue1, jsEDateDataValue2, jsEDateDataValue3, etc.

        If e.Row.DataItem("Status") = "closed" OR e.Row.DataItem("Status") = "open"" Then
            txtYourBox.Visible = True
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```